# Backbone router failing to respect trigger=false option

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-routing

Backbone.js provides a `navigate(fragment, [options])` method for its Backbone.router objects, which  does the following (per the documentation):

> Whenever you reach a point in your application that you'd like to save as a URL, call `navigate` in order to update the URL. If you wish to also call the route function, set the `trigger` option to `true`. To update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history, set the `replace` option to `true`.

Thus, simply calling `appRouter.navigate('page');` would presumably change the URL to `www.myapp.com/page` without triggering the corresponding route. However, I'm finding that my router redirects to the URL *and also triggers the page route*, despite the fact that `trigger=false` by default.

Thus, the following code:

```
$(function(){
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'home',
        'page': 'page',
    },

    home: function() {
        window.app.navigate('page', {replace: true});        
        console.log('home route');    
    },

    page: function () {
        console.log('page route');
    },

});

window.app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

produces the following console output when navigating to www.myapp.com:

```
> home route
> page route
```

when the expected console output should just be:

```
> home route
```

The method seems to be disobeying the default `trigger` option. Is this a bug in the implementation, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: does it work correctly with `trigger: false` set?

Comment: @jakee: No, `window.app.navigate('page', {trigger: false, replace: true});` still produces the same behavior. As does `window.app.navigate('page');`.

Comment: take off the `pushState: true` from the `Backbone.history.start` and try it with the original navigate call. I googled around and there might be a connection between `pushState: true` and `navigate` not working properly.

Comment: That did it. It correctly navigated to #page, while only firing the home route. Thanks! I'd really like to use this with `pushState: true` though. Is this in fact a bug in the implementation?

Comment: I don't know, my Googling produced only vague remarks about this from year 2011 and I had to patch it up by myself. I think it has to do with the pushState implementation in the js history api. But I'll add an answer and if you want to, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Backbone as of 6/28/12 (the master version on https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone) resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the `pushState: true` from the `Backbone.history.start` and try it with the original `navigate` call.

I googled around for a solution to this, but all I got was vague remarks about the history API's `pushState: true` causing the Backbone Router's navigate function not to work properly. For an example of my Googlings [this](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/17/tips-for-using-backbone-js-routers-with-html5-pushstate/) striked out article was about the best resource on the matter I could find.